# Jacobi method for complex Hermitian matrices.

Tags: numerical-methods, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, hermitian-matrices

There is the article on wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_method_for_complex_Hermitian_matrices about Jacobi eigenvalue algorithm for Hermitian matrices.

It says:

> Similar to the Givens rotation matrices, $R_{pq}$ are defined as:
> $$ 
> (R_{pq})_{m,n} = \delta_{m,n}, (m,n \ne p,q);
> \\
> (R_{pq})_{p,p} = \frac{+1}{\sqrt{2}} e^{-i\theta};
> \\
> (R_{pq})_{q,p} = \frac{+1}{\sqrt{2}} e^{-i\theta};
> \\
> (R_{pq})_{p,q} = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{2}} e^{+i\theta};
> \\
> (R_{pq})_{q,q} = \frac{+1}{\sqrt{2}} e^{+i\theta}
> $$

But the usual rotation matrix is defined with cosinus and sinus like that:
$$
\hat{\mathbf{R}}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta
\\  
\sin \theta & \cos \theta
\end{pmatrix}
$$

This matrix rotates the vector $\mathbf{v} = \begin{pmatrix} x \\ y \end{pmatrix}$ on the angle $\theta$:

$$
R\mathbf{v}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\cos \theta & -\sin \theta
\\  
\sin \theta & \cos \theta 
\end{pmatrix} 
\begin{pmatrix}
x
\\
y
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix} 
x\cos\theta - y\sin\theta
\\
x\sin\theta + y\cos\theta
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

I don't understand why that complex rotation matrix $R_{pq}$ is defined with complex exponents and what exactly it rotates?

Comment: It looks like they are tied to the hyperbolic sine and cosine. It won't be a rotation matrix, it will just be reminiscent to one.